# Code executing forever

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a python code that is taking too much time (It actually never completed)

```
imp_pos_words = ' '.join([i for i in pos_word_ls if i not in unimp_words])
```

'unimp_words' is a list of 99,000 alphabetic words
'pos_word_ls' is a list of 15,40,000 alphabetic words

I actually want to omit out all the words which are there in 'unimp_words' from the 'pos_word_ls'

PS: 'pos_word_ls' has duplicate words so i can't type cast it to a set and perform minus.

Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are checking `if i not in unimp_words` you are traversing through the entire list to find if `i` is in the list or not which takes O(n) time, where n is the length of the list. Since you're doing this 15,40,000 times, it'll be incredibly slow.

Instead what you can use is a **set** which will be much faster. This is because when you check if an item is in the set, a hash function is used to find out where `i` is in the set, and this takes O(1) time.

To convert your list `unimp_words` to a set, you can use `unimp_words = set(unimp_words)`. Now when you check `if i not in unimp_words` it should be much faster.

Comment: I'm unclear how this adds extra information that is not in the earlier answer

Answer (score 1):

Use a `set`for just the `unimp_words`.  The `i not in` lookup will be much faster.

```
unimp_words = set(unimp_words)
imp_pos_words = ' '.join([i for i in pos_word_ls if i not in unimp_words])
```

If it is a list, `if i not in unimp_words` will have to traverse the whole list *every time* it checks a word.  A set hashed lookup is much faster and your list comprehension will be about 99,000 times faster.